# Way to save image source in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, image, performance, architecture

I want to store image src in a table `pics` column `src`.

Now there's are lot of way I can do that.

Simply I can save like `imagename.jpeg` or with full set `http://www.example.com/pics/hd/imagename.jpeg`.

But due two some reasons there are disadvantages and advantages of both co-related.

Since I have multiple copies of my image on quality and size basis. 1st option is useful as I can use `HDIMAGE. $SRC` to access the images. `define(HDIMAGE, 'pics/hd/')` will be constant for HD image and so can be for `low quality` images.

But If in future I have multiple domains then I cannot access images present on other domains using the same constant.

And if I use the second option I will have advantage for multiple domains but it will be limited to only one type of pictures either HD or low quality.  Since I have only one column for storing image src.

So, I want to know how big sites like Facebook, Google, Twitter etc store their image source.  They do store in multiple domains or servers though.

Comment: You could store just the filename part of the path, and have a foreign key to a domains table, so that multiple domains are supported.

Comment: If I have low quality image and HD in different domains then? @hafler

Comment: You could add the file part to the domain in the foreign table.

Comment: What is the best way to handle images like this? @hafler

Comment: Images like what? (Please use tab-completion to get names correct - I'm halfer, not hafler - I seem to have received a notification anyway however).

Comment: @halfer many images like `_240x350`,`_32x32` etc for one mysql row or `id` of `pics` table. Both may or may not get stored physically  in same domain.

Comment: See above - use a `location` table to contain a domain and a path, e.g. `http://domain1.tld/pics/hd/` and an image table to point to that record and store `240x350.png` as the name at that location.

Comment: But where will the   `http://domain2.tld/pics/lowquality/` of `240x350.png` go??

Comment: Database tables - I'm not sure what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use BLOB datatype or store the part of the url so that when you will run the code in some different server space, as you said, you can get the server address and append that with your part-url.

Comment: Please can you clarify a bit sir I didn't  get the store url part

Comment: The path part of the url.  No need storing the left part of the url -- that's always the same.  You can 'construct' the full url when needed.

Comment: BLOB maxes at 64KB; MEDIUMBLOB (max 16MB) might suffice for images.  Beyond that, you really should go with storing the images in files on disk.